# can we change the topic name to something else other than chatter when publishing and subscribing messages?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a publisher in python and a listener in rosjava. I sent hello world under topic "chatter" from talker.py to listener.java. But when I changed the topic from "chatter" to  "uic", the publisher publishes the message but the listener doesnot receive anything. I can see the following in my terminal and see that the listener is still subscribing to the chatter topic even after i changed it in listener.java code.

INFO: Response<Success, Subscribed to [/chatter], []>
Jan 17, 2014 11:55:35 AM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1 onMasterRegistrationSuccess
INFO: Subscriber registered: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier, TopicDescription<std_msgs/String, 992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1>>>

Why is my listener still subscribing to topic chatter even after i changed it in the code?

I edited this line in the code where I changed chatter to uic:

Subscriber<std_msgs.String> subscriber =
connectedNode.newSubscriber("uic", std_msgs.String._TYPE);

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119036/can-we-change-the-topic-name-to-something-else-other-than-chatter-when-publishing-and-subscribing-messages?/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've updated the code correctly.

Java is a compiled language; did you recompile your listener after you changed it?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-17**:
My fault. Forgot to compile..it works fine now..thanks!